# SixLabors Image Sharp How to Write text to Image c#

Tags: c#, imagesharp

I have searched for a long time. I know it is part of the extended package, but I cannot seem to find any examples. Even a hello world example on how to write text to an Image Sharp image. Thanks for any help.

```
public Image DragImage {
    get {
        SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image<Rgba32> ri = new((int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height);
        //FieldName on the ri Image just created
        return ri;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.drawing/gettingstarted.html at the bottom there is a **Drawing Text**

Comment: I literally googled "ImageSharp Text" and [this](https://www.adamrussell.com/adding-image-watermark-text-in-c-with-imagesh) came back.

Comment: I tried that. The DrawingText in the lamda expression was not there. I had all the libraries installed.  I went through all the mutate properties and functions. IImageProcessingContext interface

Comment: Let me rephrase that, I did not find anything that would work. What am I missing?

Comment: I found it! I needed to install a drawing extension package that was not installed with the core product. SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing. There was one installed but it did not have the DrawText method.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the NuGet packages you'll want to reference:

1. [SixLabors.Fonts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.Fonts)
2. [SixLabors.ImageSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp)
3. [SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing)

And here's an example code to draw some text on an image:

```
using SixLabors.Fonts;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

const string text = "Sample Text";
const float TextPadding = 18f;
const string TextFont = "Roboto";
const float TextFontSize = 64f;

var image = await Image.LoadAsync("source-filename.jpg");

FontFamily fontFamily;

if (!SystemFonts.TryGet(TextFont, out fontFamily))
    throw new Exception($"Couldn't find font {TextFont}");

var font = fontFamily.CreateFont(TextFontSize, FontStyle.Regular);

var options = new TextOptions(font)
{
    Dpi = 72,
    KerningMode = KerningMode.Normal
};

var rect = TextMeasurer.Measure(text, options);

image.Mutate(x => x.DrawText(
    text,
    font,
    new Color(Rgba32.ParseHex("#FFFFFFEE")),
    new PointF(image.Width - rect.Width - TextPadding,
            image.Height - rect.Height - TextPadding)));

await image.SaveAsJpegAsync("output-filename.jpg");
```